# Web Bluetooth - Show extra info on scanning dialog

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm trying to support web-bluetooth to connect to my devices and perform a simple task (such as playing LED).
However, the device information showed on the scanning dialog when calling `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice` is not so clear. It only shows the `device name` and a random (?) hex string.
The problem here is all my devices have the same name (`AWESOME_LED`), thus it's not easy for the user to select the correct LED if all scanning items show the same device name info. As far as I know, we can not custom to add more info showing on the scanning dialog.
I come up with a new solution that is changing the device name to unique for each LED with the format `AWESOME_LED + [uniqueid]` e.g `AWESOME_LED1`, `AWESOME_LED2`, `AWESOME_LED3` so that the user can distinguish one from the others.
My question are:

- Is there any alternative solution without making the device name unique?
- If not, is there any problem / rejection / limitation from Apple or Google for my current app on App Store / Google Play by not using the same device name for all devices? I have been investigating it at [Apple forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/8442) / [Accessory Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf) and looks like there are no problems, just to make sure if anyone has faced trouble from Apple / Google.

Thanks for your help.
[Scanning dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb3qo.png)

Comment: I don't see any other way to distinguish a device without connecting. Most devices can be renamed exactly for easier distinction.

Answer (score 1):

> My question are:
>
> - Is there any alternative solution without making the device name unique?

The browser prompt is not customisable yet. One solution you highlighted already is to make your LED device name unique. If you're able to control the device, why not having one `AWESOME_DEVICE` name and a GATT characteristic you can write to that controls individual LED colors. Maybe something like:

```js
const device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [{ name: "AWESOME_DEVICE" }],
});
const server = await device.gatt.connect();
const service = await server.getPrimaryService(0x1234); // Your service UUID
const characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(0x5678); // Your characteristic UUID

// Set LED #1 to red color.
await characteristic.writeValue(
  new Uint8Array(/*ledIndex=*/ 1, /*r=*/ 255, /*g=*/ 0, /*b=*/ 0)
);
```

> - If not, is there any problem / rejection / limitation from Apple or Google for my current app on App Store / Google Play by not using the
>   same device name for all devices? I have been investigating it at
>   [Apple forums][1] / [Accessory Design Guidelines][2] and looks like
>   there are no problems, just to make sure if anyone has faced trouble
>   from Apple / Google.

None that I'm aware of.